# How to manually add hibernate mappings in Hibernate 5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I found [this(Configuring Hibernate programmatically, for real)](https://portofino.manydesigns.com/en/blog/configuring-hibernate-programmatically?) article online that does what I am asking but on an earlier version of Hibernate. Some of the methods that it’s using like `configuration.createMappings` are not found on the latest hibernate along with `org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings` class.

Below is a code snippet from it

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
Mappings mappings = configuration.createMappings();
Table table = mappings.addTable(schemaName, null, tableName, null, false);

Column col = new Column();
col.setName(name);
col.setLength(len);
col.setPrecision(len);...
```

What I want to find out is that is it possible to do what it’s doing in Hibernate 5

Comment: Have you found solution for this ?

Comment: Yes, I kind of did. In my case I had to manually read metadata from the database (datasource), and then create the xml files just in time before hibernate actually loads the mappings. I did not find a way to do it the java way as in the question.

Comment: Yeah I reached to same conclusion of creating XML of mapping then instantiating `StandardServiceRegistry`

Answer (score -1):

you can automatically creating/updating the db tables based on entity classes . You can use this hibernate property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`

Comment: That I know how to do. What I want to do is do the mappings myself instead of hibernate doing the mapping in the background.