# Adding mappings described in a database table (entity) to Hibernate's SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm in the process of migrating a Hibernate 4 application into a Hibernate 5 one. The application allows the possiblity of defining additional columns outside of the usual ones listed in an entity, which are modelled with a `Map<String, Object>` (call it `additionalFields`) in each entity (the key is the name of a field/column, while the value that field/column's value).

To model this so far we've had an entity (let's call it `FieldDefinition`) which contains the information of this mapping (the name of the field, the type, the precision or maximum length if that applies, etc.)

So, after creating the `SessionFactory`, we would use it to obtain a `session`, access all instances of `FieldDefinition` and add the mappings dynamically through `configuration.getClassMapping(entityClassName)`, `configuration.createMappings()`, and related methods.

These last methods in `Configuration` have been removed from Hibernate 5, hence the problem I'm trying to solve. If I understand correctly, with the new API I would need to:

1. Create a `SessionFactory` that understands about `FieldDefinition`.
2. Use it to access it and retrieve the `FieldDefinition`s.
3. Having the instances of these entities, create a second `SessionFactory` (because `SessionFactory` is immutable, so I cannot modify the first one), where during the creation I use the `MetadataSources.addFile()` (or `.addInputStream()`) to add `hbm.xml` files I need to create on the fly based on the `FieldDefinition` data to map the additional columns to the `additionalFields` maps (I couldn't find a programmatic way of adding mappings as was the case with `configuration.createMappings()`).

Alternatively, I can skip the first `SessionFactory` creation if I use the `DataSource` and JDBC directly, but the rest stays the same. I found [this other SO question which points to more or less the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951153/how-to-manually-add-hibernate-mappings-in-hibernate-5). Am I on the right track, or if not, what's the current recommended approach for such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a custom `org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataContributor` that is registered via a `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataContributor` file, since it is loaded through the java service loader mechanism.

There you have access to the `PersistentClass` where you can add you attributes, and at the same time you can make use of `JdbcServics` which you can use to query a table.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like the right approach, for some reason I hadn't found mentions of that interface before. Just to complete a bit your answer for any other readers, one has access to the `PersistentClass` by using `metadataCollector.getEntityBinding(entityName)`, and to `JdbcService` by `metadataCollector.getMetadataBuildingOptions().getServiceRegistry().getService(JdbcServices.class)`.